# Seeking QGIS equivalent of ArcGIS Erase tool?

Tags: qgis, erase

Is there a QGIS equivalent of the **[Erase](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000m000000)** tool in ArcGIS Desktop?

The Erase tool:

> Creates a feature class by overlaying the Input Features with the
>   polygons of the Erase Features. Only those portions of the input
>   features falling outside the erase features outside boundaries are
>   copied to the output feature class.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes there is.

It's called **Difference**, and you can access it by doing Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Difference.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In ArcGIS Desktop you can Erase without purchasing the Advanced level license by activating ETGeoWizards in a standard ArcView license.

If you right-click on your toolbar you will get a list of tools, click on "ETGeoWizards" and it will activate that tool.

After opening ETGeoWizards tool, on the left hand side there are a number of categories choose the "Overlay" cat. and "Erase" is 3rd down from the top.