# Erase method using OGR

Tags: python, ogr, erase

I'm trying to find the erase geoprocessing method as I am familiar with in ARC, but I can't seem to find it in OGR using Python. I have looked through the module OGR documentation but perhaps I missed it.

An example of the function would be even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OGR function to Erase a geometry is named Difference. I found this Python API document,[osgeo.ogr Python] (http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr-module.html)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the tool like it is it in ESRI. the input driver could be modified to your needs. Also no projection is enforced on the output currently.

```
def erase(baseFile, eraseFile, outFile): #this class performs the erase tool from ARCGIS//     erasefile must be polygon
  import os
  import sys
  import functions

  try:
    from osgeo import ogr
  except ImportError:
    import ogr

  driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('Mapinfo File')
  driver2 = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')

  feat1 = driver.Open(baseFile, 0)
  if feat1 is None:
    print 'Could not open feat1.tab'
    sys.exit(1)

  feat2 = driver2.Open(eraseFile, 0)
  if feat2 is None:
    print 'Could not open feat2.tab'
    sys.exit(1)  

  feat1Layer = feat1.GetLayer()
  feat2Layer = feat2.GetLayer()

  feature2 = feat2Layer.GetFeature(0)
  geomfeat2 = feature2.GetGeometryRef()

  feat1Layer.ResetReading()

  # create a new data source and layer
  fn = outFile
  if os.path.exists(fn):
    driver.DeleteDataSource(fn)
  outDS = driver.CreateDataSource(fn)
  if outDS is None:
    print 'Could not create file'
    sys.exit(1)
  outLayer = outDS.CreateLayer('roads', geom_type=ogr.wkbLineString)

  functions.copyFields(feat1Layer, outLayer)
  # get the FeatureDefn for the output shapefile
  featureDefn = outLayer.GetLayerDefn()

  #loop through input layer
  for inFeature in feat1Layer: 

    # create a new feature
    outFeature = ogr.Feature(featureDefn)

    # copy the attributes and set geometry
    functions.copyAttributes(inFeature, outFeature)

    #get Geometry of feature and apply the difference method on that feature
    inGeom = inFeature.GetGeometryRef()
    GeomDiff = inGeom.Difference(geomfeat2)
    #Set geometry of the outfeature
    outFeature.SetGeometry(GeomDiff)

    # add the feature to the output layer
    outLayer.CreateFeature(outFeature)
```

Comment: There is a more efficient method for erasing a whole layer with another layer. See OGRLayer::Erase in http://www.gdal.org/classOGRLayer.html.