# Splitting feature when intersecting with feature of another layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, splitting

I have a buffer layer (green polygon) which I want to split to two polygons whenever it crosses a barrier (blue line). I have been trying to use "splitGeometry" method, but I just can't get it to work.

My code so far is this :

```
while ldbuffprovider.nextFeature(feat):
  while barprovider.nextFeature(feat2):
    if feat.geometry().intersects(feat2.geometry()):
        intersection = feat.geometry().intersection(feat2.geometry())
        result, newGeometries, topoTestPoints=feat.geometry().splitGeometry(intersection.asPolyline(),True)
```

Which returns 1 for result( error) and an empty list for newGeometries.

[image]

Comment: Maybe this one here will help you: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66543/erase-method-using-ogr

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `reshapeGeometry` function of the `QgsGeometry` object for this, which cuts a polygon along its intersection with a line.

The following will intersect the buffer polygons with the lines, and add the split polygon features to a memory layer (QGIS 2.0 syntax):

```
# Get the dataProvider objects for the layers called 'line' and 'buffer'
linepr = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('line')[0].dataProvider()
bufferpr = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('buffer')[0].dataProvider()

# Create a memory layer to store the result
resultl = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon", "result", "memory")
resultpr = resultl.dataProvider()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(resultl)


for feature in bufferpr.getFeatures():
  # Save the original geometry
  geometry = QgsGeometry.fromPolygon(feature.geometry().asPolygon())
  for line in linepr.getFeatures():
    # Intersect the polygon with the line. If they intersect, the feature will contain one half of the split
    t = feature.geometry().reshapeGeometry(line.geometry().asPolyline())
    if (t==0):
      # Create a new feature to hold the other half of the split
      diff = QgsFeature()
      # Calculate the difference between the original geometry and the first half of the split
      diff.setGeometry( geometry.difference(feature.geometry()))
      # Add the two halves of the split to the memory layer
      resultpr.addFeatures([feature])
      resultpr.addFeatures([diff])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A good approximation with GDAL >= 1.10.0 compiled with SQLite and SpatiaLite consists into wrapping your layers (e.g. *poligon.shp* and *line.shp*) in an OGR VRT file (e.g. *layers.vrt*):

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTlayer name="buffer_line">
        <SrcDataSource>line.shp</SrcDataSource>
        <SrcSQL dialect="sqlite">SELECT ST_Buffer(geometry,0.000001) from line</SrcSQL>
    </OGRVRTlayer>
    <OGRVRTlayer name="polygon">
        <SrcDataSource>polygon.shp</SrcDataSource>
    </OGRVRTlayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

in order to have a very tiny buffer (e.g. 1 micron) around *line.shp* obtaining the *buffer_line* layer.
Then, we can apply symmetric difference and difference on these geometries using SpatiaLite:

```
ogr2ogr splitted_polygons.shp layers.vrt -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_Difference(ST_SymDifference(g1.geometry,g2.geometry),g2.geometry) FROM polygon AS g1, buffer_line AS g2" -explodecollections
```

Obviously, all this stuff is perfectly executable from a Python script:

```
os.system("some_command with args")
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

The answer of Jake have topological problems with the splitted polygons. I made a solution, hope this can help: https://gist.github.com/RamonLopezEscudero/844c1401f5339143da1b2b5cf7ff27bd

Answer (score -1):

You Can use Intersect tool in the Geoprocessing tab in Arcmap.