# Split linear features when intersecting another (line, polygon, point) in PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, splitting

I am new to QGIS Plugins and I got something that has stressed me a lot. I want to have a layer(Linear) split whenever it intersects another feature (in another layer). I have tried with the one at:

[Split a feature when intersecting with a feature of another layer using PyQGIS/Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72907/split-a-feature-when-intersecting-with-a-feature-of-another-layer-using-pyqgis-p/73888#73888)

and it works well. However, I want to have it split the line and not the polygon. Any help?

Comment: If you want to split a line with another line, you could look at the source code for the [Split lines with lines](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/SplitLinesWithLines.py) algorithm :)

Comment: Thanks Joseph for the quick response. Have checked this and the issue that might be complicating issues is that, I need to split, form a shapefile(layer) and load it on canvas.I think this is where it's getting tough

Comment: @Wanjohi254 Did you try the **Split lines with lines** algorithm available from the **Processing Toolbox**? It seems to do what you are looking for.

Comment: Oh my. I was so much into coding my own algorithm. Hadn't seen this @mgri Thank you. What if I want to split the lines using points?

Comment: @Wanjohi254 You're welcome. If this hint solved your issue, I will post it as an answer for helping potential future readers.

Comment: This is cool for splitting lines with lines. For the lines and points?

Comment: @Wanjohi254 I think it should be addressed as a new question because the approach will be necessarily different. It's quite impossible trying to simply match point and line coordinates because you practically always will have a missed intersection (since the point coordinates need to perfectly match the line feature). In my opinion, you should ask a new question by specifying what exactly are you looking for.

Comment: @mgri Thank you. Will figure it out. I will try something out and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the **Split lines with lines** algorithm available from the **Processing Toolbox**: its name is self-explanatory and I think it will solve your issue when dealing with lines.

For other kinds of geometries, I think the best would be to ask a separate question for each one because, otherwise, the topic would become too broad since every geometry type needs a different approach.